# How to Start PostgreSQL in Windows

Tags: postgresql

I would like to configure PosgreSQL in Windows machine.

Every time we have to recall the configuration process.

Please find the process below.

Answer (score 1):

###### Please follow below steps to configure PG in local

1. Download PG latest version
2. Create PD Data folder : and run below command
   `d:\pg14\pgsql\bin\initdb  -D "d:\pgdb\pgdata"`
3. Start DB with pgdata folder, place below in bat file and run
   `d:\pg14\pgsql\bin\pg_ctl -D "d:\pgdb\pgdata"  start -U postgres -P pgpwd -S auto`
4. Create user :
   `d:\pg14\pgsql\bin\psql postgres`

   `postgres=#CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;`

   you can create user if you want.
5. You can connect from any GUI pgAdmin or any other tools

Comment: `initdb` will create a user named `postgres` so there is no need to create one after that.

Comment: Also, the EDB installer runs `initdb` under the hood.

Comment: in my case its not created , database was created by default but user not created.